how to get value from an input
I would like to retrieve the start and end date value and apply it to two other date fields
 <Formik
                    initialValues={{
                        date_debut: '',
                        date_fin: '',

validationSchema={SubmitFormValidation}
                    onSubmit={async (values) => {
                        console.log(values.jour_mois);
                        const dataSubmit = {
                            date_debut: values.date_debut,
                            date_fin: values.date_fin,
                            

                                <FieldDateTimeFormFormik label={'Date de début *'} id={'date_debut'} submitCount={submitCount} error={errors.date_debut} widthLabel="w-[168px]" />
                                <FieldDateTimeFormFormik label={'Date de fin *'} id={'date_fin'} submitCount={submitCount} error={errors.date_fin} widthLabel="w-[168px]" />

and apply on this two input
<div className="flex gap-3">
                                            <FieldDateFormFormik
                                                label={'Début répétition'}
                                                id={'date_debut_repetition'}
                                                submitCount={submitCount}
                                                error={errors.date_debut_repetition}
                                                widthLabel="w-[168px]"
                                            />
                                            <FieldDateFormFormik
                                                label={'Date fin répétition'}
                                                id={'date_fin_repetition'}
                                                submitCount={submitCount}
                                                error={errors.date_fin_repetition}
                                                widthLabel="w-[168px]"
                                            />
                                        </div>

i tried to add initial value
const FieldDateTimeFormFormik: React.FC<Props> = ({ id, label, submitCount, error, dateMin = false, widthLabel, dateMinValue, positionnement = 'row' }) => { return ( <> <FieldDefaultFormatFormFormik id={id} label={label} submitCount={submitCount} error={error} widthLabel={widthLabel} positionnement={positionnement}> <Field className="form-select" name={id} id={id} component={DateTimePickers} dateMin={dateMin} dateMinValue={dateMinValue} /> </FieldDefaultFormatFormFormik> </> ); };

How does the FieldDateFormFormik component look? Normally, you would wire up the value property with props.values.date_debut and onChange as well as onBlur events with the corresponding formik handlers (see i.e. here https://formik.org/docs/api/formik). Then you can access props.values.date_debut where you need it

it looks like this
const FieldDateTimeFormFormik: React.FC<Props> = ({ id, label, submitCount, error, dateMin = false, widthLabel, dateMinValue, positionnement = 'row' }) => {
    return (
        <>
     <FieldDefaultFormatFormFormik id={id} label={label} submitCount={submitCount} error={error} widthLabel={widthLabel} positionnement={positionnement}>
                <Field className="form-select" name={id} id={id} component={DateTimePickers} dateMin={dateMin} dateMinValue={dateMinValue} />
            </FieldDefaultFormatFormFormik>
        </>
    );
};


Please update the code to your post, not the comment

i updated it now
